# How to git reset --hard HEAD~1 in Magit?

Tags: magit, git

I accidentally inserted 1 commit in my local master branch. I have not pushed this changed and I want to remove it. This was supposed to be in a new branch.

So, I created a new branch based on master including the commit. Then, I decided to remove this commit from local master. In my terminal, I can successfully do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Since I have been using Emacs, I tried doing the same in Magit. First, on Magit status buffer, I pressed `X` (Reset). After, I chose `h`(hard). Then, the mini-buffer asked

> Hard reset master to (default master):

I pressed enter (choosing default). After that, I decided to inspect the `git log`. I was expecting that the last local commit would be discarded. Unfortunately, it was not.

Comment: Magit's interactive rebasing could also be of help in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just move to the commit you want to reset to and then invoke the reset command, and Magit will interactively offer that as the *default* value.

Magit commands do this in general, and I recommend taking advantage of this contextual behaviour to avoid having to manually type references.

---

> This was supposed to be in a new branch

<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to create a "spinoff" branch is designed for that exact situation, and streamlines the process down to simply naming the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not answering the mini-buffer question in the appropriate manner. Instead of typing a number (such as `1` after `HEAD~`) it is necessary to insert the commit id before the last to be removed commit. Problem solved :)

Not sure if there is a way of using the number/amount of commits to go back instead of the commit id as a reference.

Comment: You *don't* need to use a commit hash.  You can enter *any* reference in any format Git recognises.  You originally entered `master` which, if you were already on the master branch, would hard-reset to the commit you were already at.